# When model has many other models and need to take them all at once in a specific order

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4

*edit How to receive all components from section in specyfic order?

I create here polymorphic solution(there should be component_type). But when i try to get it from database in that way:

```
SectionComponent.where(section_id: Section.first.id).collect(&:component)
```

(with default order in model on SectionComponent) then it iterate by SC objects and make for example 50 hits on database... How to do it in  few request? How it should be connected?

[image: schemat]

Comment: Let me see if I got it right. You want all components form a given section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SectionComponent.includes(:component).where(section_id: Section.first.id).collect(&:component)
```